# Where can I find a free post apocalyptic map generator online?

Tags: tool-recommendation, maps, post-apocalyptic, generator

I'm trying to make a map for a post apocalyptic idea I have. The landscape is your typical barren frozen wasteland caused by radiation and a large drop of temperature. I need to make a map based on the area so I can keep track on where every location I create is. Any ideas where I can find a website to make this on?

Comment: Can you edit in some more detail about what such a service would allow you to do? Do you want randomised terrain, or control over where features are placed? Do you wish the service to also include the ability to label the map? What kind of output do you want (gridded or ungridded, what file type, what size, for digital use or to be printed)?

Comment: Pretty much all of that minus the labeling.^ Gridded would be nice but I can manage without it. any reasonable size that i could print off a computer on a general piece of paper. I just need to make a large map of the landscape itself. I can add all the locations in myself once I've got that. I could care less if it's controlled or If i do it manually, I just need something to start with.

Comment: Go ahead and edit that info into your question; [comments are temporary](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of interesting generators at [Wizardawn](http://wizardawn.and-mag.com/). The [World Maps generator](http://wizardawn.and-mag.com/tool_world.php) with a Snow Climate is probably the closest to what you're looking for. You can use the Post-Apocalyptic Style if you want it to generate locations for you, or Empty if you want to do it yourself. It may need some tweaking, but it should get you off to a good start, and there are a lot of other cool generators that may help was well.

Answer (score -1):

[The Morrow Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Morrow_Project) had rules for taking an existing map, and targeting nuclear missiles on it, and determining the results.  I distinctly remember the example in the rulebook mentioning that the author had received a traffic ticket in a particular city, so used it for the example.

Answer (score -3):

[Dundjinni](http://www.dundjinni.com/) can make fantasy or future maps, and thus should suit post-apocalyptic RPGs. See the site's gallery for various examples. This software comes in both trial and paid versions.

[This generator](http://wizardawn.and-mag.com/tool_acity.php) also ought to help you immensely. It's free, online, and creates printable maps.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the Site and thanks for answering!  To improve your answer, I would suggest you could edit your answer to explain which of these generators you think would suit the question, or any experience you've had making post-apocalyptic maps, that would really help.

Comment: Ok! I made my answer more specific to the question.

Comment: Can Dundjinni *generate* random maps? I am under the impression that it is software for drawing/designing maps, not a generator.

Comment: I'm uncertain, but I've added a link that's a generator, specifically.